# HP Blade G6 - Replace original disks with bigger ones

Tags: hard-drive, hp

The 2 x 150GB harddrives in RAID1 in the actual HP Blade G6 460c are running out of space. I run MS2008R2 and RDP Sessio Host.
I have nought 2 x 450GB drives to use instead.

Instead of reinstalling everything, can I pull 1 150GB drive out, wait, insert the 450GB - wait for RAID1 to rebuild. And then to the same thing for the other 150GB drive.

This is a primary production server. I have agent based Windows backup, but not an image.
Please clarify.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes you could do this but you will need to edit the array config to expand the logical disk and the controller in the BL460c requires a cache + battery in order to allow expand/extend operations.

Alternatively if you can afford a good window of downtime you could image the server, swap the disks and re-image.

Comment: Thanks for the info tomstephens89. 
How would you suggest regarding the imaging of the server? The Blade has iLO2 - which is USB2.0 and slow as a turtle. 

Please elaborate. Thanks